# Как сделать автоудаление поста через 6 часов?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, база-данных

Подскажите, как реализовать систему автоудаления постов через 6 часов? Допустим пользователь сделал пост в 15:00, как удалить этот пост через 6 часов автоматически?

Сделать скрипт, который будет пробегаться по всем постам каждую минуту - это грузить саму систему. Да и при большом кол-ве записей, это будет долго.

Comment: Проверять при обращении к посту, если он старше 6 часов - помещать его в "скрытые"  и не отображать. Раз в сутки по крону удалять скрытые.

Comment: дак и не надо удалять каждую минуту, просто не показывайте посты, которые старше 6 часов. а удаляйте раз в день.

Comment: кхм. то же самое написал, что в первом комменте :D

Comment: @br3t это в цикле while при выводе постов добавить условие со сравнением времени?

Comment: Да, для вывода в цикле тоже, но и для просматриваемого поста, если в него зашли, например, из закладок.

Comment: не в цикле, а в sql запросе.

Comment: Здесь не обойтись без дополнительных данных, как у вас все устроенно и сколько запросов у вас на сайте.
Если вы хотите не нагружать систему нужно это делать раз в сутки, так как запрос в БД каждую минуту только увеличит нагрузку на систему!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без скрипта вам не обойтись. Можно и не каждую минуту, а раз в сутки (ночью).
А чтобы такие посты у вас не отображалась (ведь они должны быть удалены), добавьте условие при их получении.

Пример SQL условия: `time_added > NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR`

Если время хранится как unix timestamp, то не забудьте преобразовать дату в нужный формат: `time_added > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR)`

Comment: не, так не пойдет. В этом случае он будет запускаться раз в сутки (например, в 00:00), а те посты, которые, например были созданы в 9:00 и должны были быть удалены в 15:00, все еще будут висеть на сайте.

Comment: @VladZaev они у вас будут в БД. А для того чтобы они не висели на сайте и нужно условие там где они выводятся.

Comment: а можете, пожалуйста, привести пример полного запроса к БД с условием time_added, типа "SELECT * FROM table WHERE time_added > NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR" Так?

Comment: @VladZaev, да верно. Но только обратите внимание на то, в каком формате у вас хранится время. Добавил в свой ответ вариант если у вас время хранится в unix timestamp.